# Hover effect goes out of border

Tags: html, css, hover, mouseover

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/q2w4jjyt/25/), where I have a table, where on hover, its rows should change color, like this:

```
.hover-row:hover {
  background-color: #FFEFC6;
}
```

However, on the last row, the hover effect will overflow (the wrapper has some radius). Can we do something to prevent that?

I have tried with `z-index` and/or `border-radius`, but it will just not have any effect!

Comment: Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/q2w4jjyt/24/).

Comment: @alirezasafian wow, perfect, how did you do it? I mean an answer would be nice.

Comment: Give `overflow: hidden;` to `.wrap`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `overflow: hidden;` on `.wrap`.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2w4jjyt/24/)

Answer (score 1):

You aren't seeing results because your :hover class is at the top of your css. It needs to be below your base classes, otherwise cascading rules apply to it. When you move it down you can apply a border radius to it.

```
border-radius:10px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q2w4jjyt/23/

However, I would specifically target the Team 6 line with an ID so that Team 5 doesn't get the radius as well and look silly.